# Можно ли настроить прокси-модель для работы с другой прокси-моделью, для связей один-к-одному и многое-к-одному, так чтобы админка работала нормально?

Tags: django, django-orm

Можно ли настроить прокси-модель для работы с другой прокси-моделью, для связей один-к-одному и многое-к-одному, так чтобы админка работала нормально?

Тоесть хотелось бы полной совместимости решения с Django.

```
class Модель_1(models.Model): 
    поле = models.IntegerField()


class Модель_2(models.Model):
    модель_1 = models.ForeignKey(Модель_1, related_name="модели_1")


class ПроксиМодель_1(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True


class ПроксиМодель_2(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Хочу получить такой результат:

```
пм = ПроксиМодель_2.objects.get()
print(пм.модель_1)
<ПроксиМодель_1: object>
```

Comment: Вроде оно должно так работать. Получаете какие-то конкретные ошибки?

Comment: Ошибок нет но прокси модели сохраняют связи оригинальных моделей и друг с другом не работают. Решение для связей один-ко-многим и многое-ко-многим я нашёл в сети, а для остальных ничего не получается.

Comment: Больше 7 лет уже тикет висит по этой теме. Действительно, такого пока нет, решается костыльно, в том же тикете расписано. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10961

Comment: Ну вот по тикету как раз и есть решение для один-ко-многим. А вот для многое-к-одному, ничего не могу найти. Собственной соображалки не хватает, к сожалению.